# Why does this explicit broadcast not work?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am trying to send an explicit broadcast to a receiver that's dynamically registered inside an activity but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried adding the action that the intent filter is expecting but that doesn't work either. Only when I use a public implicit intent it picks up the broadcast.

Could any one tell me why? The code is for Android 8.0+ and I have marked the line inside CustomReceiver.

In summary it should...

1. Service starts, dynamically registers a CustomReceiver to listen for a implicit broadcast.
2. CustomReceiver receives implicit broadcast, tries to send explicit broadcast to MainActivity.
3. MainActivity receiver catches the explicit broadcast and does something.

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demos.democode">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".CustomService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.demos.democode;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(CustomService.customActionActivity);
        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(activityReceiver, intentFilter);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,CustomService.class);
        this.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);

        Log.d("DEMO_APP", "create");

    }

    BroadcastReceiver activityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.d("DEMO_APP", "activity receiver");

        }
    };

}
```

CustomReceiver.java - Explicit broadcast from here doesn't work.

```java
package com.demos.democode;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("DEMO_APP", "custom receiver");

        // DOESN'T WORK! this explicit broadcast doesn't work even after setting an action in - why?
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.setAction(CustomService.customActionActivity);
        context.sendBroadcast(i);

        // this implicit public broadcast works fine
        i = new Intent(CustomService.customActionActivity);
        context.sendBroadcast(i);

    }

}
```

CustomService.java

```java
package com.demos.democode;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

public class CustomService extends Service {

    protected Context context = null;
    public static String customAction = "EVENT_1";
    public static String customActionActivity = "EVENT_2";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        context = getApplicationContext();

        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                "DEMO_CHANNEL",
                "Demo App",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        );
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "DEMO_CHANNEL")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                //.setContentText("Total screen time today: " + totalTimeDisplay )
                .build();
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
        startForeground(1, notification);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(customAction);

        CustomReceiver customReceiver = new CustomReceiver();
        context.registerReceiver( customReceiver , intentFilter);

        Log.d("DEMO_APP", "service created");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        final Intent i = new Intent(customAction);

        Log.d("DEMO_APP", "service started");
        sendBroadcast(i);

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your mainactivity started before you are sending the customer broadcast from service? If not, that is the reason.

Comment: Yes the activity is started. If you run the code and check the Logcat you can see the service broadcast happens after the activity has setup the listener.

Comment: You're trying to send broadcast explicitly to activity component which can never succeed. Just because you've registered a receiver in activitys context doesn't mean activity itself is a broadcast receiver.

Comment: Not even if I have a inner class receiver in there? Does this mean I have to create a separate receiver class and explicitly target that instead?

Comment: I want to register the receiver inside the activity because I want to be able to update something such a textview in the activity on receive so if I create an external receiver class, I'm not sure how I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to launch an `Activity` using `sendBroadcast()`

In this code:

```
    // DOESN'T WORK! this explicit broadcast doesn't work even after setting an action in - why?
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.setAction(CustomService.customActionActivity);
    context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

You are trying to launch an `Activity`, so the last line needs to be:

```
    content.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am rather late to the party, but I think the error is in registration of receiver in the `MainActivity`. You have used

```
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(activityReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Which is using application context to register receiver.
It should be replaced by:

```
registerReceiver(activityReceiver, intentFilter);
```

In which the receiver will be registered for that specific activity instance of `Context`.